# Does Spacy's (version3.1) POS tagger depends on parser?

Tags: spacy, lemmatization

I am using Spacy to get POS tags. To make the code faster I used nlp.pipe and try disabling the components that I do not need. if I disable 'parser', I get very different results for AUXs and VERBs. However, the results are similar for NOUNs and ADJs.  It seems that we need both 'parser' and 'tagger' to get the correct number of VERBs and AUXs. Is my interpretation correct?

Further, the documents say that we need, 'parser' for lemmatization. But since POS tags depended on 'tagger'. But since POS tags depend on 'parser'. Do we need both 'parser' and 'tagger' for lemmatization or can I disable 'parser' for lemmatization?

Answer (score 1):

The POS tags come from rules that map `token.tag` to `token.pos` in the `attribute_ruler` component. If the dependency parse is available, there are more specific rules it can apply related to `AUX` and `VERB`. The mapping is hard to do perfectly because the `token.tag` PTB tags that come from the tagger don't make an aux/verb distinction at all.

If you need POS tags with `en_core_web_*`, you need at least `tok2vec`+`tagger`+`attribute_ruler`. You can optionally add `parser`, but it's not required.

A full description of the pipeline design is here: https://spacy.io/models#design

Comment: Thanks. That explains the difference. Do we need 'parser' for lemmatization? Is the  VERB, AUX distinction important for lemmatizer?

Comment: The current English lemmatizer has rules for VERB and doesn't apply any rules for AUX. For AUX, the lemmas are set by the attribute ruler rules. You can just check with your data for a pipeline with/without the parser to be sure. If it did make a difference, I think it would only affect forms of "be". If you need different lemmas for AUX, you can add/edit rules in the attribute ruler (e.g., "could" -> "can"). The upcoming v3.2.0 models will fix some lemmas related to contractions like "ca" in "can't" and "wo" in "won't" where there were rules missing in v3.0.0 and v3.1.0.